# run 3 variables in for loop python selenium web-driver to print all data including links

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop, selenium-webdriver

I try to get the current price, company name, and company (link-text) links in for loop using Python in selenium web-driver. this is my URLhttp://demo.guru99.com/test/web-table-element.php

```
company = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='leftcontainer']/table/tbody/tr/td/a")
price = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='leftcontainer']/table/tbody/tr/td[4]")
link = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='leftcontainer']/table/tbody/tr/td/a")
for name,rate,links in zip(company,price.link):
    names = name.text
    rates = rate.text
    url = links.get_attribute("href")
    if float(rates) <= 500:
        print(names,rates,url)
```

and it's showing error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'link'
```

please help me to print rates, company names, and links.

Answer (score 1):

You put  `.`insead of  `,` inside the zip, here is how you fix it `for name,rate,links in zip(company,price,link):`